# No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL and am trying to do a LEFT JOIN between 2 tables on Google BQ but facing an error that says "No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY, STRING"

Table2.UPC's data type is INTEGER while table1.UPC is STRING nested in a table thus using CAST to convert it in order to do a join. This query does not work even though I've already unnested the column in the first part of the query.

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT col1,
col2,
col3,
FROM table_A, UNNEST(items) AS items
WHERE DATE(createdAt) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-10-06')

SELECT col1
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.upc = CAST(table2.UPC as string)
```

Would appreciate any help I can get here in order to proceed with this query. Thank you!

Comment: In your example, the `table1` has no column `upc`. The `table1.upc` is an array and thus has to be unnested to be joined.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not, could you provide sample data of table_A & table2 which you are using in order to replicate.